# Pulse extending

Tags: digital-logic, delay

I have a logic pulse output from a system I've been doing. All I want is a system that:

1. Input a logic value (0/1)
2. Output that value for x time, even if the input changes
3. Reset

How can I achieve that?

**Edit:**

For example:
The input goes 0 then 1 every one second.
I need to get the pulse at 0sec and hold it for 3sec. Then again with the pulse at 3sec and etc

Input = {**0** 1 0 **1** 0 1 **0** 1 0 **1** 0 1}

Output = {0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1}

Comment: You need to be more specific about "even if the input changes". Goes back low is one thing, ignore another pulse or restart the time on another pulse is something else.

Comment: This sounds like either a pulse stretcher or a debouncer, but you need to be clear about what "3. Reset" actually means. What happens to the output when reset occurs?

Comment: @DaveTweed look at the edit

Comment: So you are simply subsampling synchronous data? Is there a clock signal associated with the input signal?

Answer (score 2):

Your spec is slightly unclear, but it sounds like a job for a non retriggerable monostable, plenty of choices in both 4000 series cmos and 74HC.

Comment: Specifically, the 74HC4538.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a monostable 555 timer. I drew a sketch beneath.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZSn7k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This would give a 1 second pulse if the input is high. The duration of the pulse is:

*T = R1 x C1 = 1M x 1µ = 1*

So you can change the duration of the pulse by changing the values R1 and C1.

Here's a video of someone who explains the working of this circuit very clearly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81BgFhm2vz8

Comment: Where would the output be?

Comment: Where it says output.

Comment: lol sry I didn't see that